# Custom data and calling them during a click - highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've added:

```
        cursor: 'pointer',
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                alert('x: ' + event.chartX + ', y: ' + event.chartY);
            }
        }
            series: [{
            name: 'Weak',
            color: 'red',
    data: [{
        y: 1,
        x:4,
        ticker:'KORS'
    }, {
        y: 5,
        x:2,
        ticker:'LULU'
    }]
},{name:'Strong',color:'green',data:[ {x:4,y:3,ticker:'lulu'},{x:-4,y:-2,ticker:'GPS'}  ]}

]
```

and it seems to be working. The problem is, when I click the datapoint, I'm seeing the x and y coordinates in the alert because of the code I added, but I want it to display the custom datapoints that I have added as well, namely the ticker datapoint. How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
event.point.ticker
```

Comment: Ah, Yes that works, how did you know that? I read over the API before I posted this and couldn't find where it addresses this.